# Unsupported VM Profile Version.VMWare Studio

Tags: vmware

Unable to create profile with VMWare Studio web console.

Creating profile results in following error

> Unsupported VM profile version. Use "Import Profile" from the VMs page to import and convert existing profile to the latest version.

VMWare ESXI 6.0

VMware_Studio-2.6.0.0-631426-system

Not able to find this question on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was browser compatibility issue.
It worked fine on IE.